# Can a minor's information be revealed after he reaches the age of majority?

Tags: privacy, florida, minor, court-records

There was a case of a mother who killed her daughter named Adrianna Elaine Hutto - some of the details are on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Adrianna_Hutto).

Her brother testified against their mother and he was referred to just as A.J. to protect his identity, as he was a minor back then.

The question is, if A.J. reaches majority, can his name be revealed **AND** be linked with the case?

Comment: Can't answer for Florida, but in Canada definitely not. News reports frequently refer to people "whose name cannot be revealed as they were minors at the time of the incident".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The court records generally remain sealed even after the minor becomes an adult (there are limited exceptions to the rule and both the secrecy and the exceptions are statutory matters).

The fact that there was a juvenile proceeding isn't a bar to factual statements about things that happened that name names, in general.

Who is bound by juvenile court secrecy rules is largely a function of the scope of the contempt of court power of the court in the actual juvenile court proceeding. Usually, it is limited to the parties and people in "privity" with them (like their lawyers and staff of their lawyers and court officials). The extent to which it applies to a witness can be a tricky matter to analyze.